# php turkish months NOW() function

Tags: php

I have one question for the php date time.

I have `join_time` in my database table. When i create new post it is posted like this : `2014-08-28 01:02:57`

I am using `NOW()` function.

My question is how can i show this datetime with `<?php echo $join_time ;?>` like this :

`28 August 2014` or `28 Ağustos 2014`

So I want to take `2014-08-28 01:02:57` and turn it into `28 Ağustos 2014`

Comment: [strftime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker How do I edit with in echo ?

Comment: you want `NOW()` to enter the date time in to the db like `28 Ağustos 2014`? or you want to take `2014-08-28 01:02:57` and turn it into `28 Ağustos 2014`?

Comment: @Alex I want to take `2014-08-28 01:02:57` and turn it into `28 Ağustos 2014`

Answer (score 3):

A quick way to do it is use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to create a timestamp from the date you've got, then format it with [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php):

```
echo strftime('%e %B %Y', strtotime('2014-08-28 01:02:57'));
```

This will output `28 August 2014` or `28 Ağustos 2014` depending on the current locale. For more on that see: [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).

---

*Note:* The `%e` modifier to `strftime` is not supported on Windows. There the modifier `%#d` can be used in its place.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
<?php

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'tr_TR'); // set locale

$str = '2014-08-28 01:02:57'; // your timestamp

$justDate = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, ' ')); // get only date, trim to first space

$date = new DateTime($justDate);
$result = $date->format('d F Y'); // format date

echo $result;

?>
```

Turns 2014-08-28 01:02:57 in to 28 August 2014

Not sure about the setlocale working, it should, but if not you could do some array work with a table of english to turkish month names

With an array:

```
<?php

$langArr = array('8' => 'Ağustos'); // just complete this

$str = '2014-08-28 01:02:57'; // your timestamp

$justDate = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, ' ')); // get only date

$date = new DateTime($justDate);
// you dont need to format it in an array, i just did since its easier than adding spaces
$result[] = $date->format('d'); // day
$result[] = $langArr[$date->format('n')]; // month numeric for array
$result[] = $date->format('Y'); // year

echo implode(' ', $result);
?>
```

Comment: *"but if not you could do some array work"* - Which is what my answer stands at helping the OP. Downvoted for it too. I might end up deleting it.

Comment: yea i confirmed that setlocale appears to only work with `strftime()` from manual "LC_TIME for date and time formatting with strftime()" ... so yea array work will probably need to be done. derps answer should be the best tho but its not working for me.

Comment: *Hm*... interesting. I had a look at the answer; looks promising. I'll just delete my answer. However, something real strange is going on tonight. I put in an answer earlier, got 3 upvotes for it. Points didn't register. I get a downvote for my answer, and that registered lol - Oh well, I flagged both of my answers and will let Stack have a look at it.

Comment: hmm thats very strange indeed! hopefully the mods will sort it out!

Comment: I'm sure they will. They're probably super busy right now; maybe it's happening to some other people also and/or they've got a bug in the system somewhere that has a higher importance than "points" lol - *Cheers*

Comment: yea i dont have it installed i think. but i just wanted to offer a diffrent answer using an array. im bored

Comment: @Alex you created a really nice help. But I have different opinion. 

`<?php setlocale(LC_TIME, 'tr_TR.UTF-8');  echo strftime("%d %B %Y", strtotime($join_time)); ?>`  In this way the problem can be answered.

Comment: @Alex; and fred-ii; I just saw your reply thanks for all your help. But Mustafa-ozturk; 's answer is a perfectly and very easy to use.